# Delete elements from array within range

Tags: c++, arrays

I tried to make an integer function that return the new length of array after deletion.

Function :

```
int delete_array(int arr[], int &length, int index, int index2) { 
//code 
return length;
}
```

For example :

> User input, length = 5
>
> Lets say the array is : 1 2 3 4 5
>
> User input, index = 1
>
> User input, index2 = 3
>
> delete(array, length, index, index2)
>
> The output should be : 1 5

Note : no pointer or vector answer please.

Comment: what do you expect for the return value of your function?

Comment: length parameter as return

Comment: Get a `std::vector<T>`, arrays in C or C++ are always fixed size and must be reallocated should you want to resize them.

Comment: You can't really erase stuff from an array. You can make a new array without the stuff you want gone, or you can copy stuff over the stuff you want gone and update the length.That's pretty much it. If you don't need to maintain order, look into `swap`.

Comment: Notice that `delete` is a reserved C++ keyword, which you cannot redefine (except as `operator delete`) See [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and read a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html)

Comment: Read more about [C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), and if you cannot use them, define your own `class` containing a buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int delete_array(int arr[], int &length, int index, int index2) 
{ 
    int numOfElements = index2 - index + 1;

    memmove(arr + index, arr + index2 + 1, numOfElements * sizeof (int));

    length -= numOfElements;

    return length;
}
```

Comment: **Aboce code won't compile on C++** (e.g. try with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) since `delete` is a C++ keyword. See [this reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  :) Actually you cant compile. i just copied function prototype from post.. i will edit forr name..

Comment: What you mean messed up? I dont think it is related with this function.